# Create JSON User-Object in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

Given a back-end in Node-Js that allows users to be created with the following schema:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/user
Authorization: {{adminToken}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "userID": "test",
 "userName": "test",
 "password": "asdf"
 
}
```

A corresponding interface is now created in React, which communicates with the BackEnd and enables the creation of users. The function to create a user looks like this in React:

```
function createaUser(userID, username,password) {
    /* const hash= Buffer.from(`${userID}:${password}`).toString('base64') */
    console.log(userID)
    const hash="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySUQiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJEZWZhdWx0IEFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IgQWNjb3VudCIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjE2NDE1NjgyNzgxNDUsImlhdCI6MTY0MTU2Nzk3OH0.mJff9nuqgHXZVQfWbjeWed3JIRAm2N2s0CYpnXoMyv4"
    var safe ={'userID':userID, "userName": username, "password":password};
    
var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(safe));
console.log(data)
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}`},
        body: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',data}
        
        }; 
        return fetch('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)
.then(handleResponse)
.then(userSession => {
return userSession;
});}
```

However, only an empty object is created. So username,userID and password are not recognized. Where is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Just post `safe` as it is. Don't convert it to json and stringify. It may work. and also add `"accept: */*"` to your requestOptions.

Comment: the requestOptions options now look like this: **const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}`},
        body: {'Content-Type': 'application/json','userID':userID, "userName": username, "password":password,"accept":"*/*"},
        
        
        };** It still doesn't work.

Comment: const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept':"*/*"},
        body: safe 
        
        }; 
        return fetch('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)

Just try this. Because you need to have content-type and accept in the header part. the data alone enough in the body part.

Answer (score 0):

React is definitely small-step, but the solution looks like this:

```
function createaUser(userID, username,password) {
    
    const hash="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySUQiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlzQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciI6dHJ1ZSwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJEZWZhdWx0IEFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IgQWNjb3VudCIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjE2NDE1NjgyNzgxNDUsImlhdCI6MTY0MTU2Nzk3OH0.mJff9nuqgHXZVQfWbjeWed3JIRAm2N2s0CYpnXoMyv4"
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}`,'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userID: userID, userName: username, password:password })
             
        }; 
console.log(requestOptions)
        return fetch('https://localhost:443/user/', requestOptions)
.then(handleResponse)
.then(userSession => {
return userSession;
});}
```